# What's the difference between Spring Cloud Bus and Spring for Apache Kafka?

Tags: spring-cloud

Using Spring for Apache Kafka, or Spring AMQP, I can achieve message pub/sub. Spring Cloud Bus uses kafka/rabbitmq to do the approximately same things, what's the differencce between them?

Answer (score 6):

Spring Cloud Bus is an abstraction built on top of Spring Cloud Stream (and hence kafka and rabbitmq). It is not general purpose, but is built for sending administrative commands to multiple nodes of a service at once. For example, sending a refresh (from spring cloud commons) to all nodes of the user service. There is only one channel, where in spring cloud stream there are many. Think of it as distributed spring boot actuator.